# Constraints versus validation groups in Symfony2

Tags: php, forms, validation, symfony

I have enabled `validation_groups` in my form by

```
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'translation_domain'    => 'general',
        'data_class'            => 'Software\Bundle\Entity\User',
        'attr'                  => ['novalidate' => 'novalidate'],
        'cascade_validation'    => true,
        'validation_groups'     => ['registration']
    ]);
```

and User.yml file contains

```
    emailAddress:
        - NotBlank:
            groups: [registration]
```

However in my form builder method I do have extra custom constraint

```
    $options = [
        'label' => 'word.email_address',
        'constraints'=> [
            new HasUsername($this->getOption('uuid'))
        ]
    ];

    return $builder->add('emailAddress', 'email', $options);
```

Problem is that the one from form builder is never called due to the fact that `validation_groups` is enabled. Because when I disable `validation_groups` then custom one is being called.

Is it possible to have the `validation_groups` constrains and constraints in the form builder work at the same time together?

The reason I need to call custom constraint in form builder is because I need to pass important variable `uuid` in order to check properly to which `uuid` user belongs to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Default in your validation group attribute

```
'validation_groups'     => ['registration', 'Default']
```